# How to solve the infinite loop in reportviewer? winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I am working with reportviewer in visual studio 2010, but when I open the report for the first time the data loads correctly, but when I change to another report and try to return to the first one, the reportviewer stays on loading.

I tried with IsPostBack but it gives me an error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odjuJ.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CheckManagement
{
public partial class BeneficiariesDebtsViewer : Form
{
    public BeneficiariesDebtsViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BeneficiariesDebtsViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Report data source code...
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }

            beneficiariesDebts.Clear();
            LoadBeneficiaryDebts loader = new LoadBeneficiaryDebts();                
            BeneficiariesDebts debts = loader.LoadData();

            foreach (BeneficiariesDebts.BeneficieriesDebtsTableRow row in debts.BeneficieriesDebtsTable)
            {
                beneficiariesDebts.BeneficieriesDebtsTable.AddBeneficieriesDebtsTableRow(row.BeneficiaryID, row.BeneficiaryName, row.TotalDebt, row.BeneficiariesTypes);
            }

            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)            
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hubo un problema al realizar la operación:\n" + ex.Message,
                            "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }            
    }
  }
}
```

I really appreciate your attention and help.

Comment: you should NOT do: beneficiariesDebts.BeneficieriesDebtsTable.AddBeneficieriesDebtsTableRow. it changes the foreach loop.

Comment: Hi @urlreader I don't understand can you get me more information, please

Comment: put break at this line: beneficiariesDebts.BeneficieriesDebtsTable.AddBeneficieriesDebtsTableRow(row.BeneficiaryID, row.BeneficiaryName, row.TotalDebt, row.BeneficiariesTypes); step cross it, then check the # rows in debts.BeneficieriesDebtsTable, you will find the # changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it in the following way:

```
try
        {
            
            beneficiariesDebts.Clear();

            LoadBeneficiaryDebts loader = new LoadBeneficiaryDebts();
            BeneficiariesDebts debts = loader.LoadData();

            foreach (BeneficiariesDebts.BeneficieriesDebtsTableRow row in debts.BeneficieriesDebtsTable)
            {
                beneficiariesDebts.BeneficieriesDebtsTable.AddBeneficieriesDebtsTableRow(row.BeneficiaryID, row.BeneficiaryName, row.TotalDebt, row.BeneficiariesTypes);
            }


            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            MessageBox.Show("La carga puede tardar unos minutos","Nota");

        }
```

I added a MessageBox.Show which allows the page to reload and in this way I managed to prevent the report from hanging.

Answer (score 0):

IsPostBack doesn't exist in a winform project but only in Asp.net.

Try to delete the if with IsPostBack and rerun the project.

Luc

Comment: Hi @lucdm I already removed the code snippet but how can I do to avoid the infinite loop? since if I enter the report for the first time everything loads fine, but when entering the report for the second time it stays loading

Comment: Hi @Ana I don't have a reliable answer because don't remember a lot about ReportViewer. Try to move the code from Load event to Activated event. Have you already tried to follow urlreader advice?